# Conflicting Chi Squared and Cramers V result

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, categorical-data, chi-squared-test, cramers-v

I'm trying to test whether ski skill level has an impact on an athlete's motivation to visit a resort. I have three skill-level categories and three motivation categories.

I have calculated my chi-squared value ($53.03$) and my $p$ value is $1.065E-08$, which is much lower than the critical value of $15.51$ at $0.05$ with $8$ degrees of freedom. I think that means I cannot reject my null hypothesis (that there is no relationship). Or is that wrong?

But my Cramer's V result is $0.287$, stating that there is a limited association between the categories. Which do I believe? Or what do these conflicting results mean?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have misinterpreted how you calculate the significance threshold for a chi-squared test. See for example from [this link about chi-squared independence tests,](https://www.scribbr.com/statistics/chi-square-test-of-independence/) which shows that the chi-square value exceeds the cutoff and is significant.

[image]

Your sum chi-square value of $53.03$ is *really high*. You are correct that this test requires $8$ degrees of freedom and consequently a cutoff of $15.507$. But your interpretation is wrong...your chi-squared value has far exceeded the cutoff, which is shown by your incredibly low p-value (which is in scientific notation to denote how low it is). Therefore, there is no surprise that your test has a Cramer's V coefficient like yours. There is clearly some association between your two factors.

Just as a side note, it appears your first row total is incorrect (it should be $63$ if I'm not mistaken). I would adjust that so your test statistics are completely accurate.

Comment: Hi Shawn, thanks so much. I did notice the error in my first row and forgot to update it here but thanks for pointing that out! I see, so as long as my chi squared value exceeds the 15.507 which it does, I can say that there is significant relationship between the two?

Comment: Yep, thats correct!

Comment: thank you so much! saved the day :)

Comment: No prob. Feel free to accept the answer by clicking the checkmark next to it if it answers your question.